# Randomize numbers within a subset

Tags: java, random

I have a array of integer numbers (say 1,2,3,4,5 or 1,2,3, ... 10 or 1,2,3, ... 50) from which I would like to get a random set of numbers ordered differently every time. Is there a utility method to do this?

e.g. for 1,2,3,4,5 post randomization it might be either [1,5,4,2,3 or 2,1,3,5,4 or 3,1,2,4,5 or ...]

I would like to know if there is a java utility method / class which already provides this capability?

Comment: If you want it to be ordered differently every time you will eventually run out of unused permutations. What then?

Comment: As long as it is ordered differently and getting the same order once in a while is fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Collections.shuffle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random))?

That won't help directly with an array, but if you convert it to a `List<Integer>` it'll work. (You can't use `Arrays.asList` with an `int[]`, unfortunately.)

Alternatively, you can implement a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) yourself very easily - in fact, that Wikipedia page even has an implementation in Java :) (I'd change it to take a `Random` reference as a parameter, however - you don't want to create a new instance of `Random` every time you call it.)

Comment: (+1) and the conversion is done using `Arrays.asList(array)` if the array is of non-primitives

Comment: @Bozho: Thanks, fixed the `asList` reference.

Comment: and http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html can help with that - `toObject(..)`

Answer (score 1):

see [java.util.Collections.shuffle](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle)
Your array needs to be an colletion. You can use [java.util.Arrays.asList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(java.lang.Object[])) for this.